# How do I change the background color of a tabbed page in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller

I need to change the background color of the currently tabbed page in my UITabBarController. I've searched through every stackoverflow post I could find but nothing worked for me. I thought there would be something like `UITabBar.Appearance.SelectedImageTintColor`, just for the background color but it doesn't seem so.

For example, I want to change the color of that part when I am on the right tab:

[image: I want to change the color of that part when I am on the right tab]

Does someone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use the `SelectionIndicatorImage` Property of the UITabBar and generate a completely filled image with your desired color using the following method:

```csharp
private UIImage ImageWithColor(CGSize size)
{
    CGRect rect = new CGRect(0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
    UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(size);
    using (CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
    {
        context.SetFillColor(UIColor.Green); //change color if necessary
        context.FillRect(rect);
    }
    UIImage image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

To initialize everything we override `ViewWillLayoutSubviews()` like this:

```csharp
public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews() 
{
    base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();
    
    // The tabbar height will always be 49 unless we force it to reevaluate it's size on runtime ...
    myTabBar.InvalidateIntrinsicContentSize();

    double height = myTabBar.Frame.Height;
    CGSize size = new CGSize(new nfloat(myTabBar.Frame.Width / myTabBar.Items.Length, height));

    // Now get our all-green image...
    UIImage image = ImageWithColor(size);
    
    // And set it as the selection indicator
    myTabBar.SelectionIndicatorImage = image;
}
```

As mentioned in [this article](http://kotaeta.com/67355247) (google translating it step by step when necessary lol) calling `InvalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` will force the UITabBar to reevaluate it's size and will get you the actual runtime height of the tab bar (instead of the constant 49 height value from XCode).

Comment: Works great. Thats what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

You could invoked the following code in your UITabBarController

```
public xxxTabBarController()
{
   //...set ViewControllers

   this.TabBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Red;
}
```

#### Update

```
//3.0 here is if you have three child page in tab , set it as the current value in your project
//
var size = new CGSize(TabBar.Frame.Width / 3.0, IsFullScreen());

this.TabBar.SelectionIndicatorImage = ImageWithColor(size,UIColor.Green);
```

```
 double IsFullScreen()
    {
        double height = 64;
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0))
        {
            if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate.GetWindow().SafeAreaInsets.Bottom > 0.0)
            {
                height = 84;
            }
        }
        return height;
    }

    UIImage ImageWithColor(CGSize size, UIColor color)
    {

        var rect = new CGRect(0, 0, size.Width, size.Height);
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0);

        CGContext context =  UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
        context.SetFillColor(color.CGColor);

        context.FillRect(rect);

        UIImage image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
        return image;
        
    }
```

Comment: This changes the entire tab bar color for me. Can I just change the background color of the tab that im in? I will provide an image so you can image what I'm trying to do.

Comment: It worked in the end but I had some problems with the GetWindow(). The other answer worked a bit better, because TabBar.InvalidateIntrinsicContentSize() updates the height to the actual height of the tab bar. But thank you for your answer. It helped us alot with finding the final answer :)